# Why don’t you go to Hawaii for like 3 years or something?

Tags: word-usage

[image]

This sentence is right?

> • Why don’t you go to Hawaii for like 3 years or something?

Isn't it correct to say "stay" instead of "go"?

In this context, a verb "go" has meaning of "stay", doesn't it?

Comment: Why don't you go somewhere. is not Why don't you stay somewhere. [Is this sentence right. Please learn how to ask a question properly with the verb be.] stay and go are unrelated.

Comment: The cited usage is really just the same as *I went home for Christmas*. Where ***went*** is the past tense of the verb ***to go***, which can be adverbially modified by ***for Christmas*** or ***for three years*** to convey the meaning *[go somewhere and] **stay there for some specified period of time***.

Comment: I think we need more context to properly understand what is being said. The word "like" makes the text very casual, it is frequently used in some parts of the UK and disliked (in that usage) in other parts. I would consider shortening the sentance to be *"Why don’t you go to Hawaii for 3 years or so?"* (where *"so"* means *"thereabouts"*). You could even use *"Why don’t you go to Hawaii for about 3 years?"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very casual in style, but it is grammatically correct for this style of English.

It wouldn't be correct to say "stay" on its own, since the person isn't in Hawaii now, so they have to "go" to Hawaii.  In context "go to" means "travel to and stay in"

Answer (score 1):

This sentence makes sense. If you wanted to use stay, “stay to Hawaii” wouldn’t be correct since staying doesn’t indicate any travel like to would. The correct form would be “stay in Hawaii” since Hawaii is a proper noun of a location :)

Comment: Hi~! :D Yeap, I know at least it is wrong to use "stay" with a preposition "to".